# How to fit big equation in beamer, with out undefined control sequence error

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{subequations}
     \begin{align}
    \mathcal{L}&=\left(\mathcal{T}-\mathcal{V}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}L\left(\psi(\zeta_{i})-\frac{L_{i}}{L}\chi_{i}(1)\right)  \nonumber \\  
     \mathcal{\bar{L}}&=\left(\frac{\beta^4}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\,\hspace{-0.05in} \left( \psi(\eta)\right)^2 \diff\eta + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\gamma_{i}}{2}\, \int_{0}^{1}  \hspace{-0.05in} \left( \chi_{i}(\xi)\right)^2 \diff\xi \right)-\nonumber \\ &\quad  \left(\frac{1}{2}\, \int_{0}^{1} \hspace{-0.05in} \left(\frac{\partial^2\psi(\eta)}{\partial \eta^2}\right)^2 \diff\eta  +\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\alpha_{i}}{2}\, \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\partial \chi_{i}(\xi)}{\partial \xi}\right)^2 \diff\xi \right)+\nonumber \\ &\quad \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}^{*}\left(\psi(\zeta_{i})-\frac{L_{i}}{L}\chi_{i}(1)\right) 
     \end{align}
     \end{subequations}

    \end{frame}
```

Comment: If only what the `\diff` command is…Please post a compilable code.

Comment: This is the complete code of my first slide

Comment: your code is not compilable. Missed are `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` (at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having completed and a bit simplified your code, I propose to use the medium-size fractions from `nccmath` for the fractional coefficients,  replace the `\hspace{-0.05in}` with a simple `\negthinspace` (`\!`) and most `\left( ... \right)` with `\biggl( ... \biggr)`. Also improved the placement of a couple of exponents.

Unrelated: you don't have to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
 \newcommand*{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathsf{d}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \begin{subequations}
     \begin{align}
    \mathcal{L}&=(\mathcal{T}-\mathcal{V})+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}L\biggl(\psi(\zeta_{i})-\frac{L_{i}}{L}\chi_{i}(1)\biggr) \nonumber \\
     \mathcal{\bar{L}}&=\biggl(\mfrac{\beta^4}{2}\!\int_{0}^{1}\! \bigl( \psi(\eta)\bigr)^2 \diff\eta + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mfrac{\gamma_{i}}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\! \bigl( \chi_{i}(\xi)\bigr)^2 \diff\xi \biggr)-\nonumber \\
     &\phantom{{}={}} \biggl(\mfrac{1}{2}\! \int_{0}^{1}\! \biggl(\frac{\partial^2\psi(\eta)}{\partial \eta^2}\biggr)^{\!2} \diff\eta +\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mfrac{\alpha_{i}}{2}\! \int_{0}^{1}\!\biggl(\frac{\partial \chi_{i}(\xi)}{\partial \xi}\biggr)^{\!\!2} \diff\xi \biggr)+\nonumber \\
     &\phantom{{}={}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}^{*}\Bigl(\psi(\zeta_{i})-\frac{L_{i}}{L}\chi_{i}(1)\Bigr)
     \end{align}
     \end{subequations}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic question: is there a question about the different fraction styles typesetting? Your mention of nccmath made me want to check more packages with different fraction styles.

Comment: I'm not sure. This package is an extension of amsmath, which defines, more generally, a `\medmath` command and a `medsize` environments, and several other facilities. Some questions here say it has some bugs, but I never met them. Caveat: it has to be loaded *before* `mathtools`  (problems if you use `\shortintertext`).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not compilable. Missed are \begin{document} and \end{document} and `\diff` is not defined (with `\newcommand` or by use package which define it).

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\newcommand\diff{\,\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{subequations}
     \begin{align}
\mathcal{L}
    & = \bigl(\mathcal{T}-\mathcal{V}\bigr) +
        \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}L\Biggl(\psi(\zeta_{i}) - \frac{L_{i}}{L}\chi_{i}(1)\Biggr)        \notag \\
\mathcal{\bar{L}}
    & = \Biggl(\frac{\beta^4}{2}\int_{0}^{1} 
        \bigl( \psi(\eta)\bigr)^2 \diff\eta + 
        \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\gamma_{i}}{2}
        \int_{0}^{1} \bigl(\chi_{i}(\xi)\bigr)^2 \diff\xi\Biggr) - 
                                                \notag \\
    & \qquad\Biggl(\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1}
        \biggl(\frac{\partial^2\psi(\eta)}{\partial\eta^2}\biggr)^2 \diff\eta  + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\alpha_{i}}{2}
        \int_{0}^{1}\biggl(\frac{\partial \chi_{i}(\xi)}{\partial \xi}\biggr)^2 \diff\xi \Biggr) +        \notag \\
    & \qquad \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}^{*}\Biggl(\psi\bigl(\zeta_{i}\bigr) -
    \frac{L_{i}}{L}\chi_{i}(1)\Biggr)
     \end{align}
     \end{subequations}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

In above MWE I cleanup all clutter in your code and replace `\left(` with `\Biggl(` and `\right)` with `Biggr)`. Also I introduce `\bigl` and `\biggl`, and `\bigr` and `\biggr)` on appropriate paces in equations. Also I define `\diff` command.

Is this solve your problem?